# Swift 4 error when POST data via HTTP

Tags: swift, api, http, http-post

I have problem when send *complain* data to server with API.
My send func. As result i got 404 error (screenshot below)

```
func complain(jsonData: [String: Any], token: String) {

    print(token)
    request(complainURL, method: .post, parameters: jsonData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"])
        .responseString {(response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                if let error = JSON(data)["errors"].string {
                    self.delegate?.failureRequest(error: JSON(error).dictionaryObject!)
                } else {
                    self.delegate?.updateRequest(rosemaryJSON: JSON(jsonData), byState: .complain)
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("FAIL: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
    }
}
```

my JsonData

```
 let param: [String: Any] = [
            "details": "\(AlertTextField!.text!)",
            "subject": "Complain",
            "client_id": (EVTUser.user?.id!)!
        ]
```

Comment: Many things depend on your server side, but usual servers return 404 (meaning Not Found) when the path in the request URL is wrong. Are you 100% sure that the url in your code is correct? Have you tested that in other ways like using Postman?

Comment: @OOPer yes is correct... i changed my send func using Alamofire, now i have no error but params still don't arrive

Comment: Please add the Alamofire code into your question, and describe precisely what _params still don't arrive_ means. Those may be some clue to check your server side behavior. But it's far better you check the server side code or server logs.

Comment: @OOPer i update my code

Comment: What result do you get? Just showing code provides no info about your server...

Comment: @OOPer i got .success, i think i have trouble on my server because good has no issue right?

Comment: Please try to describe the issue better. Readers do not know anything about what sort of app you are making and how your _complains_ API works. If you get success, what's the problem?

Comment: @OOPer it works now, i will write one more post for people to describe how i fix that..

Answer (score 0):

my **ORIGINAL** code was ...

```
func complain(jsonData: [String: Any], token: String) {

print(token)
request(complainURL, method: .post, parameters: jsonData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"])
    .responseJSON {(response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            if let error = JSON(data)["errors"].string {
                self.delegate?.failureRequest(error: JSON(error).dictionaryObject!)
            } else {
                self.delegate?.updateRequest(rosemaryJSON: JSON(jsonData), byState: .complain)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print("FAIL: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
}
}
```

i just change **responseJSON** to **responseString** and it works now! I got success.. 
Hope it will help someone.